# Hide a user during connect not working with goinstant

Tags: javascript, goinstant

```
goinstant.connect(url,{visible: false}, function (err, connection, lobby) {...}
```

I get the following JavaScript error when using parameter visible:

```
ArgumentError: invalid option(s) provided: visible
```

Comment: The latest version of our javascript api (which includes support for the `visible` flag) hasn't yet been deployed to the GoInstant cdn. I'll add another comment when this happens.

Comment: The code was deployed last night. Your example code should work just fine now!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that is now fixed.